# Расположение файлов в Maven проекте

Tags: java, maven

В Maven-проект необходимо добавить txt файл, из которого программа будет считывать данные. Где мне следует его хранить: в src/main/resources или создать отдельную папку на уровне проекта? Спасибо

Comment: Храните в src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

Храните в src/main/resources, только ести там параметры проекта лучше использовать app.properties

Answer (score 0):

> в src/main/resources

да, папка для подобных вещей и предназначена.

Answer (score 0):

You can save files on your project like this:

[image: Like this]